# move error mv: cannot stat 'foldername': Input/output error

Tags: mv

I try to move a folder to another one, but this error appears:

```
mv: cannot stat 'Anim': Input/output error
```

I even can not open that directory in file manager. Why this happens?

Comment: If this on an ext partition or NTFS?

Comment: @Dorian it's an external hard disk with NTFS format.

Comment: You can try to install ntfsfix with `sudo apt-get install ntfs-3g` and then you can run `sudo ntfsfix /dev/(device name)` on the drive.  With any fix like this, be aware that it could result in data loss.  This is why backups are important before it's too late.

Comment: thank you for your advice. But it give this error `disk is corrupted`.
So I back up my files and then I formated my disk with `gparted`.

Comment: So unfortunately, it looks like it was toast anyways.  Glad you were at least able to copy the data, that's the important part!